# Согласование во множественном числе (1)

Tags: множественное-число

***Овсянников***, его семья и члены его команды не оплатил счет за проживание почти на 4 миллиона рублей... **Не оплатил** или **не оплатили**?

Answer (score 3):

**Не оплатили**, конечно. Ведь речь идёт о группе людей, а не об одном Овсянникове. **Не оплатил** было бы правильно в такой конструкции: **Овсянников не оплатил** счёт за своё проживание, проживание своей семьи и членов команды...